# Angular 2 Divide templates on authorized and non authorized

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

In my angular2 app I have different pages. Every page except login page should contain menu area. I tried to make like that first:

```
RootComponentTemplate:

    <menu></menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But I did not find the way to hide menu tag if the user is in login page.

I think that another way is to add menu tag to template of every component, but it seems a little bit weired.

Example:

```
ExamplePage

<menu></menu>
<content></content>

Example Page1

<menu></menu>
<content1></content1>
```

What is the right way to add common component to every page? Or is there a good way to say the root component to hide menu in login page?

I also found this question/solution , is it the right way?

[Good template strategy for authentication in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100271/good-template-strategy-for-authentication-in-angular-2)

Comment: I think that if the user is in login page he is not authenticated, so you can check if the user is authenticated or not to hide the menu using *ngIf directive, like in the example you referenced